# Excel VBA - Wait for Chrome to be ready (has loaded the PDF file)

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'd like to retrieve the PDF text of a PDF file in Excel.

For this, I Shell launch Chrome with the PDF file as a URL, send keys Ctrl A + Ctrl C + Alf F4 and retrieve the Clipboard text.
Even if I wait for the Chrome Window to be active, I don't know when Chrome has fully loaded the PDF file.
I could wait for a "certain" time but it's not really determinist.

Is there an API SendMessage or else that could tell if Chrome has completed its job ?
Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: You may consider to open the pdf with word and then transfer the data to excel if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: CLIP returns weird things for a PDF file, not the text.
Other options also require to ensure the readiness of the tool and file.
I tried the WebBrowser Control, InternerExplorer Application but both do not natively manage PDF of course.
So I remained on Web Browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) that can handle PDF natively and looped on Select All / Copy by sending keys until I get something in the Clipboard. Not ideal but it seems to work. The .xlsm file is here -> https://www.cjoint.com/c/MKuhxyzWhK5

Comment: Ok, sorry I did not fully get your explanation. I'ill try this again.

In the meantime I built a more "sophisticated" version of the Macro as I tried to adapt the timers based on the PC CPU power. Here it is ->  https://www.cjoint.com/c/MKvr6vX2Iv5

Comment: Thank you for this link. Thing is that I don't even understand the README ! This is github language. What am I supposed to do with the ZIP file ? "$ make install datadir=/usr DESTDIR=/tmp/buildroot-xyz2000>" What will this do ? Bascially I don't have the slightest clue on how to install this Poppler on Windows.

Comment: As an old boy I don't feel embarrassed using a command line. The open source Xpdf command line tools (https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) seem to be light and simple and has a lot a pdfto<something> exe files in the bin64 or bin32 folders. That might be a good option too.